# @ExceptionHandler not firing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

This has been asked a few times in Google-land, but I can't seem to apply those resolutions to my situation.  My J2EE application uses Spring and I was previously using SimpleMappingExceptionResolver to intercept Exceptions to show a friendly error page for my users.  One of the guys on my team has his own package and is using an extended Exception class as a vehicle to communicate validation errors to his users.  So now every time a user enters invalid data, it triggers an exception page.  He refuses to change his code (even though I thing he should), so now I am forced to make error handling a package- or controller-specific thing.

I've tried to leverage the `@ExceptionHandler` annotation to do this, but it doesn't seem to be firing.  What am I doing wrong?  I am expecting a call to `dmapproval` to essentially return the `applicationError` view.

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class ExecutiveApprovalController {

    /*omitted stuff*/   

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public String routToErrorHandler(Exception anExc) {
        return "applicationError";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/dmapproval", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String dmApproval(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {    

        throw new RuntimeException(); // just for testing exception logic
    }

    /*omitted stuff here, too*/
}
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Does your dispatcher actually have `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in it or did you manually set up the various view resolver/method resolver components?

Comment: I am using `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in my webmvc-config.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet looks fine; the only difference between your code and something that I have working is that I annotate the exception handler method like this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
```

As an aside; this is far less elegant than using `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` (which it sounds like you already know!).  I'd ask you rogue team-mate to reconsider his validation approach and use Exceptions only in exceptional circumstances ;)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Something else must be wrong; even after using `Throwable.class` I'm still receiving the give-up message `Error 500: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException` in the front-end.  And unfortunately it doesn't seem I'll be able to change his mind.

Comment: Does it work if you change it to: @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)

Comment: No, no it doesn't.  I really expected that to work.  Perhaps there is some configuration preventing it from behaving properly?  Does Spring have a `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler` class with a `nothingWorksTheWayYouExpectedItTo` property I can set to false?

Comment: It must be some configuration elsewhere. Are you certain that you've removed the SimpleMappingExceptionResolver configuration?  Failing that I wouldn't know what else to suggest I'm afraid, my only other route would be to look into @ControllerAdvice, but I fear that might not be fine grained enough for you...

Comment: SimpleMappingExceptionResolver is commented. Any idea where I could have gone wrong in the configuration? Would posting more code help in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this config in your servlet-context.xml

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver">
```

Comment: Adding a reference to AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver did not help, either.